# Android Studio limites de la pantalla

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, bitmap, touch

tengo un Bitmap en el canvas que lo muevo por la pantalla con un On Touch event. La pregunta es, como puedo hacer para que la imagen que muevo no se salga de la pantalla? Tipo establecer unos limites por donde pueda moverla y que choque con el borde de la pantalla y no me deje pasar. Gracias

Es es el codigo que tengo:

```
    public class Juego extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{

    Bitmap super_esfera;
    int esferaX = 200;
    int esferaY = 200;

    public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        super_esfera = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.super_esfera);

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        Bitmap indexcanvas = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(super_esfera, 200, 200, true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(indexcanvas, esferaX, esferaY, paint);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        esferaX = (int)event.getX()-100;
        esferaY = (int)event.getY()-100;

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Para limitar el movimiento dle bitmap, puedes hacerlo añadiendo unos condicionales en el metodo que mueve el bitmap. Comparando la posicion actual del objeto con la posicion de los bordes y si la posicion del objeto es menor que los bordes de la pantalla se puede mover, pero si es mayor o igual no se mueva.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta ya pude hacelo